# Permissions to run docker container on self-hosted windows azure devops agent

Tags: windows, docker, azure-devops

In an azure devops build pipeline running on a self-hosted windows agent, I am trying to execute a tool that run a docker container.
Unfortunately I get this error :

```
Failed to start: failed to create container: Error response from daemon: CreateFile c:\Users\BUILDAGENT\.aerokube\selenoid: Access is denied.
```

The build agent is configured with its own windows local user "BUILDAGENT", so he has permissions on the `C:\Users\BUILDAGENT\` folder

Looking at the process manager, I see that except com.docker.service, the others docker processes are running with the user that launched the Docker Desktop (my coworker).
If I restart windows and relaunch docker myself, the settings selected by my coworker ("Disk Image Location" for instance), are not restored...

Is there a way to make docker run as a daemon on startup with a specific user (service or system user, but not mine or my coworker) ?
Once this is done I guess I just have to give permissions for that specific user on the C:\Users\BUILDAGENT\ folder to solve my issue, right ?

Update :

I added my BUILDAGENT user in docker-users group, and it solves the permission issue, but I still would like to run docker as a service, instead of login as my local user to launch it with its GUI...

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question,  If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I still would like to run docker as a service, instead of login as my local user to launch it with its GUI

You could try to create a **task scheduler** to run docker with that specific user when your PC starts.

Please check this thread [How to create an automated task using Task Scheduler on Windows 10](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-automated-task-using-task-scheduler-windows-10) for some more details.

In this case, docker will start automatically every time you start your computer.

Comment: Thanks but I finally ended up using a Mac that doesn't reboot...